# If series is not uniformly convergent, can we still integrate term by term?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis

We know that if $\sum a_nx^n$ converges uniformly, then we can integrate term by term. So this is just a sufficient condition, right? Does there exists a series not converging uniformly and still we can perform term by term integration? I am looking for some general results in this direction.

Comment: This is a complicated question in general but Fourier series can be integrated term by term regardless of uniformity of convergence or boundness in the sense that if $c_0$ is the free term of a Fourier series of a lebesgue integrable periodic function $f\in L^1([0,2\pi])$ and $F$ is any indefinite integral of $f$, $F(x)-c_0x$ has as Fourier series the term by term integral of the Fourier series of $f-c_0$ up to a constant and the convergence is uniform for the periodic $F-c_0x$ regardless of how the Fourier series of $f$ behaves (could even be divergent ae)

Comment: This is helpful. I will look further into this stuff(and Fourier series). Thanks.

Comment: The main issue is not termwise integration of power series, but integration with uniform vs. pointwise limits: if $f_n \rightarrow f$ on a set $A$, does $\int_A f_n(x)\, dx \rightarrow \int_A f(x)\, dx$? The last limit is just numbers but the first is functions: pointwise or uniform or something else? Here *measure theory* is important, as it gives practical conditions to justify commuting integration and pointwise limits. See the Dominated Convergence Theorem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a power series like that, there's a radius of convergence $r$ - and for any $s<r$, the series converges uniformly for $|x|<s$. With that, we can use the uniform convergence to integrate term by term with the same radius of convergence.

The only place we can't use uniform convergence? The boundary.

And on that boundary... [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem). If the series converges at a point on the boundary, then it's the limit of the values inside, approaching head-on. For example, this theorem applied to the series $\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots$ gives us the alternating harmonic series $\ln(2)=1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\cdots$.

Relating to the term-by-term integration your interested in, that logarithm series is the integral of $\frac1{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots$, and we then have
$$\int_0^1 1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots\,dx = \left.x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots\right|_{x=1} = \ln(2)$$

Comment: So I have to look beyond the power series. Can I get some example of a non-uniformly convergent series which is not a power series where term by term integration is performed? I am going to accept your answer after some time. I am expecting new comments.

Answer (score 0):

In response to a comment by the proposer to another A:

For $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ let $g_n(x)=0$ for $x\not \in [2^{-n-1},2^{-n}]$ and let $g_n$ be integrable on $[2^{-n-1},2^{-n}]$ such that $\sup \{|g_n(x)|: x\in [2^{-n-1},2^{-n}]\}\ge 1.$ And such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1g_n(t)dt=0.$

Let $g_0(x)=0$ for all $x.$

For $n\ge 0$ let $f_n=g_n-g_{n+1} .$

Then $\sum_{j=0}^nf_j=g_0-g_n=-g_n$ converges point-wise, but not uniformly, to $0$. And $\sum_{j=0}^n\int_0^1f_j(t)dt=-\int_0^1 g_n(t)dt$ converges to $0.$

For example, for $n\in \Bbb Z^+:$ Let $a_n=(2^{-n-1}+2^{-n})/2.$ Let $g_n$ be linear on $[2^{-n-1},a_n]$ and on $[a_n,2^{-n}]$ with $g_n(2^{-n-1})=0=g_n(2^{-n})$ and $g_n(a_n)=n.$

You can easily produce variations on this theme.

Comment: Thank you. This is a nice example.